# Accessing Azure SQL Data Warehouse data via HTTP REST API

Tags: sql-server, azure, rest, azure-synapse

I am given the task to consume data from an instance of Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

The data must be consumed by an on-prem machine which cannot directly access the internet and is able to access internet resources only via an HTTP Proxy, which allows ONLY HTTP/HTTPS traffic.

To the best of my knowledge, Azure SQL DWH doesn't expose HTTP APIs, except for DB management purposes (start/stop the service, etc.).

Is there any software/service that I can use to enable the querying of Azure SQL DWH tables from the on-prem machine via the HTTP Proxy?

Many thanks

PS: until now I have found two candidate solutions:

- an open source software: https://github.com/hellofiremind/jdbc-sql-rest (A primitive REST Api wrapper for SQL calls to a JDBC compliant database)
- a cloud service: https://skyvia.com/connect/sql-data-warehouse-odata (Restify Your Azure SQL Data Warehouse Data)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bad idea ... better to get your admin to open outbound 1433 ... but this method should work:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-SQL-Database/Using-a-TCP-proxy-to-connect-to-SQL-Database-over-VPN/ba-p/390962